# {% translate s %} passed in {% include ... with s=s %} not in .po file

Tags: python, django, translation

I have a basic feed I am trying to render in my Django project. I have created a **feed.html** file as a base template for slight variations of the same type of feed. Among those variations, is the header of the feed. Importantly, I want that header to be translated into multiple languages.

I have implemented this "variation" idea using `{% include "feed.html" with variation=variation %}`. However, I am having problems translating those variations.

I am trying the following in **feed.html**:

```
{% translate header %}
```

Then in one of the templates where I want a variation of **feed.html** I have:

```
{% include "feed.html" with header="Header" %}
```

The problem is, the string "Header" does not make it into any of my `.po` files and therefore remains untranslatable.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use different syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, the string "Header" does not make it into any of my .po files and therefore remains untranslatable.

If that means that the `makemessages` command doesn't extract the string, then yes, it won't, because there is no string. Only a variable. That variable could take any value at all, `makemessages` cannot possibly trace that back to all possible locations where you might be setting the value for `header`. `makemessages` can only extract what you *literally* put into `{% translate %}` tags or `_()` function calls directly.

> The caveat with using variables or computed values, as in the previous two examples, is that Django’s translation-string-detecting utility, django-admin `makemessages`, won’t be able to find these strings.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation

You'll want to translate the header value before passing it:

```
{% include "feed.html" with header=_("Header") %}
```

Comment: So, is there an alternative, working solution to my code? Is there a way to use the translate tag into the include tag?

Comment: See update. I'm not entirely sure that works, but it should.

Comment: Can you call functions inside a template tag..?

Comment: @thebjorn https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters